# Sum of filtered values in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

In Power BI, I have a dataset that contains columns with ID and linked number.

It looks like this:

```
[ID_01] [Number_01]  [ID_02] [Number_02]  [ID_03]  [Number_03]
    A        12         A         03         C          45
    A        43         B         12         B          64
    B        02         B         78         C          19 t
    C        14         A         51         B          23
```

What I need is, for each line, to get the sum for each ID, which would look like this:

```
[ID_01] [Number_01]  [ID_02] [Number_02]  [ID_03]  [Number_03] [SUM_A] [SUM_B] [SUM_C]
    A        12         A         03         C          45       15      00      45
    A        43         B         12         B          64       43      76      00
    B        02         B         78         C          19       00      80      19
    C        14         A         51         B          23       51      23      14
```

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve it ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok in PowerQuery / M, and is dynamic to any number of columns  rather than just three sets of ID/Number

I'm sure there is a two-line version of this somewhere, but it might get you started

```
 let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
 // set up merge table that can be merged into index
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"_"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter"[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column", {"Index", "ID"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Number]), type number}}),
SecondTable= Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[ID]), "ID", "Total", List.Sum),
// merge the two table
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Index"},SecondTable,{"Index"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
ColumnsToExpand = List.RemoveFirstN(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Merged Queries", "Table2"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),1),
#"Expanded Part2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand ),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Part2",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```